# Cloning a card with Tribute

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Forthcoming Nessian Demolok has the following abilities.

> Tribute 3 *(As this creature enters the battlefield, an opponent of your choice may place three +1/+1 counters on it.)*

> When Nessian Demolock enters the battlefield, if tribute wasn't paid, destroy target noncreature permanent.

Assuming the reminder text is complete and accurate, what happens if you cast [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone) choosing a Nessian Demolok? Specifically, does your opponent get a chance to pay tribute?

---

By the letter of the rules, choices for "As this permanent enters the battlefield" occur before the permanent the battlefield<sup>[CR 614.12a]</sup>, but doesn't Clone's replacement effect happens at the point it enters the battlefield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your opponent gets a chance to pay the Tribute. From the Clone rulings:

> Any enters-the-battlefield abilities of the copied creature will trigger when Clone enters the battlefield. **Any "as [this creature] enters the battlefield**" or "[this creature] enters the battlefield with" abilities of the chosen creature will also work.

This is the same behavior as when you Clone a Triskelion; the Clone will get 3 +1/+1 counters.

Comment: duh, should have checked the rulings! That's what I thought, but the rule wordings is flaky. (The choices supposedly happen before the permanent enters the field, but the replacement effect should only come into when it does...)

Comment: What happens if you clone a Marath? I assume it checks for the cost of the clone?